# Error on data moving from Sqlite to Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to migrate from Sqlite to Postgres with `gem 'yaml_db'`. On my locale development everything goes fine. But when I tried to do the same on production server I see the error: 
`PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  new encoding (UTF8) is incompatible with the encoding of the template database (SQL_ASCII)`

What should I do to keep my data and move it from one DB to another?

**database.yml**

**on the locale computer**

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

**on the server**

```
production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

But the file has UTF-8 encoding:

```
$ file -i data.yml
data.yml: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: is it possible that you didn't initialized you pg database with the right encoding?

Comment: I do it for first time in my life, so everything maybe) I'd install it step-by-step like it written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092807/installing-postgresql-on-ubuntu-for-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: try running this command `psql -U USER DATABASE -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'`. replace USER and DATABASE

Comment: db doesn't exists. thanks, your comment helps me. it happens because I was looking in two guides at the same time. Migration is done.

Comment: then you should close the question as well :)

Comment: @devanand do you mean, that I should answer my own question? or what?

Comment: yes, in a way you should mark the question as answered. but i don't know how to do :)

Comment: @devanand I think it'll be very stupid to post thi like an answer. If you don't mind I'll just delete it.