# Error occured while installing do_postgres (0.10.16) Bundler canot continue. Make sure 'gem install do_postgress -v '0.10.16' succeeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

Am trying to install snorby on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am having this error message:

> Error occured while installing do_postgres (0.10.16) Bundler canot continue. Make sure 'gem install do_postgress -v '0.10.16' succeeds

I have tried `sudo apt-get install libpq` and it still has not resolved it. The header postres.h seems to be missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing PostgreSQL on Ubuntu for Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092807/installing-postgresql-on-ubuntu-for-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 postgresql-server-dev-9.5 libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 try `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-10`